# Mantain Facebook SDK up to date?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I downloaded the Facebook SDK for Android and I'm using it in my app for a while. I want to make sure I'm using the most recent version (fixes, patches, etc).

I need a release version, backwards compatible, and up to date. I'm using Facebook SDK in an already released app and it doesn't have to break any existing code or do unexpected things.

All I can find is the master branch in GitHub. Are there no release versions with details (what has changed, etc.), how do I know if my version is up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got the sdk from github by forking the master branch, then you can just do something like:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

As explained here: [Pull in upstream changes/Fork A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)

---

**Edit**

What you need to stay up to date with is the graph api (which you can do with the [Developer Doadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)).
The android SDK is just a wrapper for http requests and webviews which are interfaces for the graph. It also of course uses the main facebook application (katana) if installed on the device, but that updates automatically so you don't need to worry about that.

If you still want to make sure that you have the recent stable version of the sdk then you should pull from the master, and you can check what the updates are from the [Commit History](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master).

Comment: But there's no versioning, with changelog, etc. I want to know what I'm updating, if it's backwards compatible, if it make sense for me to update...

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the version number of your current Facebook SDK, it's in `facebook-android-sdk\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookSdkVersion.java`